# Django How to pass username in a predefined template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I created a templates for header/footer and imports, if I want to acess the username in my header template I cant do that because it has no views. How can I pass the username to the header template?

header_template.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('home/partials/header.html')
def header(element):
    return {'element': element, }
```

Import in Template

```
{% load header_template %}
{% header context %}
```

Usage in the template:

```
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <a class="btn btn-primary display-4" href="{% url 'home:profil' %}">Profil</a>
                        {% else %}
                            <a class="btn btn-primary display-4" href="{% url 'home:login' %}">Login</a>
                        {% endif %}

Thanks for your help.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take `context` in your tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('home/partials/header.html', takes_context=True)
def header(context, element):
    return context | {'element': element}
```

Read more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

My opinion, you are don't need this, The cause for every new tag in template - a wrong logic.